# How to get real object from Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get real object from Jquery selector result? Example:

```
 $("form").first().id != $("form").first().attr("id")
```

so this mean result somehow wrapped/delegated with jquery how to unwrap it?

Comment: Just a tangential tip, `.attr("id")` would already get the `id` from the first, no need to chain `.first()` in there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$("div")[0]` or `$("div").get(0)`, substituting 0 for the index of the element you want.

If you have multiple DOM elements that you want out, you can use [.toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/).

Answer (score 7):

The left operand is incorrect because here:

```
$("form").first().id
```

[`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first) returns a jQuery object, so you can't use `id` (a DOM element property) on it. To get the DOM element wrapped by the jQuery object you use array deferencing:

```
$("form")[0].id
```

Or [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get):

```
$("form").get(0).id
```

The following should evaluate to `true`:

```
$("form")[0].id == $("form").first().attr("id")
```

And therefore this should be `false`:

```
$("form")[0].id != $("form").first().attr("id")
```